# Not able to find Sync in Team Explorer in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, synchronization, team-explorer

I want to use the sync function in team explorer to sync the master repository to local, but I can't find it. Am I having a problem with the settings?

My team explorer screenshot
[image]

What it should look like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As your first screenshot shows, the Git features have moved out of the Team Explorer window.  The incoming/outgoing commit list that was previously in the TE Git Sync page are now in the Git Repository window.  You can open that window via View->Git Repository.